# Airflow - Distribute flow execution on multiple workers

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a DAG that looks like this:

```py
with DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_ID,
    schedule_interval='@once',
    default_args=default_args,
    ) as dag:
    
    def function_1(value):
        return value+1
        
    def function_2(value):
        return value+2
        
    values_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    
    for value in values_list:
        execute_func_1 = PythonOperator(
            task_id=f"{str(value)}_pyth_op_1",
            python_callabale=function_1,
            op_kwargs={'value': value}
        )
        
        execute_func_2 = PythonOperator(
            task_id=f"{str(value)}_pyth_op_2",
            python_callabale=function_2,
            op_kwargs={'value': value}
        )
        
        execute_func_1 >> execute_func_2
```

It executes everything in parrallel just as intended, but on only one worker (out of 3) and it runs out of memory. If I increase the worker's memory it works fine.

Is there any way to distribute the execution on multiple workers?

Comment: considering that you might be using CeleryWorkers, each worker listens to their respective queue to get their tasks hence for multiple worker nodes, you might have to setup appropriate queue and you would have to pass "queue" argument in PythonOperator to enable such multi-node execution (queue argument itself comes from BaseOperator). refer :  https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/models/baseoperator.html#BaseOperator

Comment: another reference which might shed some light on what happens under the hood : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/executor/celery.html

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, if you are concerned about workers going OOM while executing the task and doesn't want to increase worker memory, then something that would be worth you time is [1] "WORKER_CONCURRENCY" with this override you can control how many active task can a worker handle at a give time.

for instance if it's set to default try reducing the number abit and see what works best for you.

[1] https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.9/configurations-ref.html#worker-concurrency